# Como debugar código em PHP?

Tags: php, debug

Por exemplo, em javascript temos o `console.log` para debugar, descobrir onde estão os erros, etc. E em PHP, quais seriam **as melhores maneiras**?

Comment: Há vários depuradores para PHP prontos a usar. Geralmente, encher tudo de prints não é a melhor solução, seja em PHP seja noutras linguagens. Breakpoints/Watches/etc. são melhores (não sei a tradução para português disto)

Comment: Eu utilizo o xdebug, e um plugin para utilizá-lo no Sublime Text 3 (adicionar breakpoints, etc).

Comment: Pessoal, editei a pergunta para evitar que ela seja fechada por ser baseada em opiniões pessoais. Aos interessados olhem no histórico de edição e, se necessário, melhorem ou revertam alguma alteração

Comment: Em vez de `var_dump`, muitas vezes uso: `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $variavel, true ) . '</pre>';`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Considere usar a função `debug_backtrace` do PHP, mas somente em desenvolvimento, pois a função tem um grande custo computacional.

Documentação: http://php.net/debug_backtrace

---

Use assim:

```
$is_dev = true;

function debug() {
    global $is_dev;

    if ($is_dev) {
        $debug_arr = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        $line = $debug_arr[0]['line'];
        $file = $debug_arr[0]['file'];
    
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');

        echo "linha: $line\n";
        echo "arquivo: $file\n\n";
        print_r(array('GET' => $_GET, 'POST' => $_POST, 'SERVER' => $_SERVER));
        exit;
    }
}

// ...

if (/* ... */) {
    debug();

    /*
    Nesse ponto, a execução do script será interrompida
    e serão impressos o nº da linha atual, o nome do arquivo e as variáveis
    $_GET, $_POST e $_SERVER
    */
}
```

Fazendo algumas adaptações para o seu caso, a função fica ótima para debugar o código!

Veja também:

- `var_dump` - https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php
- `print_r` - https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php
- `var_export` - https://www.php.net/var_export
- `debug_print_backtrace` - https://www.php.net/debug_print_backtrace
- `__LINE__` e `__FILE__` - https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Se vai citar essa pergunta, é bom comentar também do `debug_print_backtrace`. Outro ponto é que `console.log` de javascript é diferente do `debug_backtrace`. Um imprime uma variável, enquanto o outro imprime o caminho até aonde ela é executada. Se pelo menos citar esses pontos ganha meu +1 por deixar mais claro sua resposta.

Answer (score 10):

Em PHP, o equivalente direto de `console.log` seria `print_r`, `var_dump` e o `var_export`.

Se tiver o `xdebug` habilitado, também pode usar o `xdebug_var_dump` que exibe a saída de modo também pre-formatado e colorido.

Agora, quanto ao melhor modo de debugar? Bem, isso depende de cada caso. Pode ser imprimindo as telas como falei, ou então com uma IDE integrada com `xdebug` ou equivalente pré-definido e podendo até mesmo setar breakpoints.

### Sumário curto, com principais diferenças

- [**print_r**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php) : mais simples. Não exporta com tipos
- [**var_dump**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php): mais detalhado. Exporta tipos. Útil em casos aonde tem valores 0, '', NULL.
- [**var_export**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-export.php): parecido com var_dump, porém exporta um código que pode ser reusado novamente no seu Script.

### Avançado

Também é possível debugar uma aplicação durante a execução do código. Para isso vai precisar de uma IDE e algum módulo que, quando seu script é executado, permite que qualquer ferramenta que se conecte em uma porta específica possa interagir com seu script.

Responde passo a passo isso é motivo para uma outra pergunta exclusiva, porém uma referência para saber mais sobre isso pode ser visto em [Depurando o Código-Fonte do PHP no NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging_pt_BR.html)

Ainda que seja o meio mais avançado, ele pode ser complexo de configurar e mais demorado do que testar com print_r e die. Mas é excelente em aplicações mais complexas.

Answer (score 7):

Em [php](/questions/tagged/php) nós temos o `var_dump()` que retorna o elemento a ser debugado e todas as suas propriedades.

Mencionando a [documentação do php](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php) o `var_dump()` dve ser utilizado assim:

> Exemplos
>
> **Exemplo #1 Exemplo da **var_dump()****
>
> `<?php
> $a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
> var_dump ($a);
> ?>`
>
> O exemplo acima irá imprimir:
>
> ```
> /* mostrará:
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   int(1)
>   [1]=>
>   int(2)
>   [2]=>
>   array(3) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(1) "a"
>     [1]=>
>     string(1) "b"
>     [2]=>
>     string(1) "c"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Exemplo #2 Exemplo da **var_dump()****
>
> `<?php
>
> $b = 3.1;
> $c = true;
> var_dump($b,$c);
>
> ?>`
>
> O exemplo acima irá imprimir:
>
> ```
> float(3.1)
> bool(true)
> ```

Answer (score 6):

A opção mais prática para realizar debug no PHP é instalar um debbuger como [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) ou [Zend Debugger](https://www.zend.com/topics/Zend-Debugger-Installation-Guide.pdf) em conjunto com um IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, PhpStorm etc) essa combinação permite:

- Que o código PHP seja pausado a qualquer momento com um breakpoint.
- Inspeção das das variáveis e seus respectivos valores.
- É possível fazer profile de desempenho, o que ajuda a detectar de forma eficiente gargalos ou lentidão.

## Instalação xdebug

Vá até http://xdebug.org/ baixe a versão especifica do seu php e jogue o arquivo na pasta de extensões (geralmente a ext).

## Configuração

Abra o php.ini e adicione as seguintes linhas e reinicie o apache para colocar em vigor as alterações.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable = On
```

Assim o Xdebug será ativado via demanda, ou seja é necessário informar a query string `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` em todas as páginas que deseja ativá-lo. Para facilitar o processo existem extensões para o Firefox ([xdebug cute](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cute-xdebug/)) e Chrome ([xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en)) que fazem esse trabalho.

Caso queira ativar o debug em todas as requisições feitas adicione essa linha:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
```

Comment: A opção `xdebug.remote_autostart=On` é útil caso esteja testando algo via console. Não testei pra ver se o impacto na performance local é muito grande, porém é bem mais prático :) Mesmo via browser e com o add-on para inserir o cookie enche o saco.

Comment: @gmsantos ele roda mais lento, se vc usa o phpmyadmin a ide pausa o código até dar 'resume', é meio incômodo. Eu gostei mais dos add-on.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei onde você está desenvolvendo, mas se fosse em um sistema Linux seria legal você desabilitar os erros pelo `php.ini` mudando as chaves `expose_php = off` e `display_erros = off`. Assim seu sistema ficaria mais seguro e poderia visualizar os erros no kernel.

Pelo Ubuntu você utilizaria o seguinte comando:

```
$: tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar uma lib chamada dephpugger. É como o ipdb para python ou o byebug para ruby.
Você digita xdebug_break() no seu código e ele para no terminal.

https://github.com/tacnoman/dephpugger

Answer (score 2):

Coloque esta linha no ponto que vc quer debugar:

```
echo "TRACE at:".__FILE__.":".__LINE__.":<br\><pre>". debug_string_backtrace()."</pre>"; exit;
```

Comment: function debug_string_backtrace() { 
        ob_start(); 
        debug_print_backtrace(); 
        $trace = ob_get_contents(); 
        ob_end_clean(); 

        // Remove first item from backtrace as it's this function which 
        // is redundant. 
        $trace = preg_replace ('/^#0\s+' . __FUNCTION__ . "[^\n]*\n/", '', $trace, 1); 

        // Renumber backtrace items. 
        $trace = preg_replace ('/^#(\d+)/me', '\'#\' . ($1 - 1)', $trace); 

        return $trace; 
    }

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer saber o valor de uma variável, pode apenas utilizar:

```
die(var_dump($variavel));
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma estratégia que funciona em quase todos os ambientes é escrevendo um arquivo de log:

```
<?php
$test = 'My variable value';
file_put_contents('./my-log.txt', 'test='.$test);
```