# Imagens de site não aparecem no iphone nem no tablet iOS

Tags: php, ios, aplicação-web, imagem

No site: http://viladivanomoveis.com.br/?page=produtos&prod=Poltronas
as imagens não aparecem ao acessar de iphones ou ipads, suspeito que seja por causa deste codigo php que redimensiona a imagem original:

```
<a href="?page=item&prod=<?php echo remover($exeprod['produto']);?>">
 <img src="thumb.php?img=admin/<?php echo $spr[0];?>&x=300&y=300&q=80" alt="" title=""/>
</a>
```

Alguém sabe como fazer aparecer as imagens ou o motivo de não aparecer?

Comment: As imagens aparecem por um breve momento e depois somem... Para confirmar a suspeita, troque o src pra linkar direto pra imagem. O inspector do Safari não acusa nenhum erro JS, só um 404 pra `http://viladivanomoveis.com.br/get-tweets.php?url=undefined`

Comment: Já tive problemas se semelhante e era por as imagens originais estavam em 32 bits color CMYK e não 24 bits RGB, verifique isso...

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi... O que coloco no lugar de '_src_'?

Comment: @Jader Verifiquei, as imagens estão em 'png 8bits RGB'

Comment: `<img src="LINK-REAL-DA-IMAGEM.jpg">` . . . Acho que vc vai ter que investigar o que esse `thumb.php` faz, confira [Como debugar código em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6037/201)

Answer (score 1):

O motivo de não aparecerem é que o arquivo que deveria ser uma imagem em src (um jpg,png, gif ou coisa do tipo) é um .php (thumb.php). O navegador dos dispositivos não "aceita" carregar um php como uma imagem... o que você pode fazer é renomear o arquivo thumb.php para thumb.jpg por exemplo.
Assim o navegador irá aceitar exibir seu conteúdo como imagem.

Ou...

Chame um método que lhe retorne logo a url completa da imagem, e preencha esse valor em src.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se seu PHP está enviando o *mime-type* correto nas imagens:

```
<?php

   header("Content-type: image/png");
   ...
```

O tipo é necessário para que os navegadores saibam o que é aquela informação que está sendo servida.

Normalmente o servidor manda o tipo correto quando se tratam de arquivos estáticos, porém quando você gera seu arquivo, é necessário "avisar" os browsers.

Quando se trata de gerar HTML pelo PHP isto não é necessário, pois o próprio PHP já manda o *mime-type* padrão do HTML.