# PHP editar imagem

Tags: php

O meu problema é que o ficheiro `img_editar.php` não esta a mandar as imagens para a base de dados (é para adicionar varias imagens ao mesmo tempo), o ficheiro adicionar imagem funciona muito bem, clico na opção editar e quando mudo por exemplo o nome da imagem sou obrigado a mudar as imagens, só que a mudar as imagens estas não são enviadas para a BD, eu até tenho a função para manter as imagens `if($_FILES['img']['size'] > 0)` mas não esta a funcionar.

```
<?php
    include "bd.php";
    include "_config.php";
    include "admin.php";

  $target = "../upload/"; 
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['img']['name']);
  $pic=($_FILES['img']['name']);


 $data=date("ymd");
$query="update portfolio_imagens set nome='".$_POST['nome']."', descricao='".$_POST['descricao']."', cliente='".$_POST['cliente']."', publicacao='".$data."' where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result=mysql_query($query);
 $picas=0;
    echo $query;
    if($_FILES['img']['size'] > 0){
      //echo "1";
  $query2="update portfolio_imagens set  imagem='".$pic."' where id=".$_GET['id'];
  $result2=mysql_query($query2);
  $picas=1;
}

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target) || $picas=1) // 
  { 

 echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success fade in\">

          <i class=\"fa fa-check-circle fa-fw fa-lg\"></i>
          <strong>Notícia criada com sucesso!</strong> 
         </div>";
         echo '<script>window.location.href = "adicionar.php?msg=1";</script>';

 }else{
  echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger fade in\">

          <i class=\"fa fa-ban fa-fw fa-lg\"></i>
          <strong>Erro!</strong> 
         </div>";
         echo '<script>window.location.href = "adicionar.php?msg=2";</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: se fizerem favor metam me isso em modo codigo que nao sei como se faz aqui

Comment: [Como debugar código em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6037/201)

Answer (score 1):

Veja, eu coloquei um `if` para verificar se o array contendo o nome da imagem existe e se ela retorna algo diferente de vazio. Caso ela retorne é porque o usuário enviou também uma imagem além do nome, descrição etc.. Então ele adiciona uma variavel com o conteúdo para fazer com que adicione um update da imagem no `$result` e já faz o upload da imagem.

```
<?php

include "bd.php";
include "_config.php";
include "admin.php";

$target = "../upload/"; //Diretório aonde irá salvar
$target = $target . $_FILES['img']['name']; //Caminho completo
$pic= $_FILES['img']['name']; //Pega nome do arquivo com extensão

$ID = $_GET['id']; //ID

if(isset($_FILES['img']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){ //Verifica se existe o array name e se ele é diferente de vazio

  $condition_aditional = ", imagem='".$pic."'"; //Linha adicional no UPDATE
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target); //Move o arquivo de foto
}


$result=mysql_query("UPDATE portfolio_imagens SET nome='".$_POST['nome']."', descricao='".$_POST['descricao']."', cliente='".$_POST['cliente']."', publicacao='".$data."' ".$condition_aditional." WHERE id=".$ID.""); //Executa a Query

  if($result){ 

 echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success fade in\">

          <i class=\"fa fa-check-circle fa-fw fa-lg\"></i>
          <strong>Notícia criada com sucesso!</strong> 
         </div>";
         echo '<script>window.location.href = "adicionar.php?msg=1";</script>';

 }else{
  echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger fade in\">

          <i class=\"fa fa-ban fa-fw fa-lg\"></i>
          <strong>Erro!</strong> 
         </div>";
         echo '<script>window.location.href = "adicionar.php?msg=2";</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: nao funciona continua a fazer o mesmo

Comment: @Alisson Acioli, seria interessante você informar a alteração que foi feita.

Comment: sim obrigado pela explicação mas nao está a dar :s