# xdebug - xampp php7

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

Boa tarde galera, pesquisei em diversos lugares em como ativar o xdebug e encontrei algumas soluções, mas nenhuma delas funcionou aqui. A forma mais simples e que sempre utilizei foi desmarcar o ; da linha zend_extension = "C:xamppphpextphp_xdebug.dll", porém no meu php.ini não existe mais essa linha, só incluindo ela nao funciona também :/

Já tentei reinstalar o xampp, porém, sem sucesso..

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Adicione [essas linhas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153793/91) também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa colocar essas linhas no php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

e baixar o "php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll" de acordo com a versão do seu PHP, neste [link](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php).