# Xdebug no Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

Estou com problema para ativar o xdebug no xampp, visto que não encontro as diretivas no xampp para configurar o xdebug.

Como faco para adicionar a extensao do xdebug no php.ini do xampp?

Comment: [Como debugar código em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153793/91)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como debugar código em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6037/como-debugar-c%c3%b3digo-em-php) (a resposta do @rray parece resolver bem o problema)

Comment: Debugar é tranquilo, o caso é instalar o xdebug no xampp, pois na versão nova do xampp eu nao consegui e nem encontrei nenhuma configuracao do xdebug no php.ini

Comment: Geralmente o php.ini não vem o xdebug configurado, vc adicinou aquelas linhas da resposta? o caminho da dll xdebug ficou como?

Comment: Qual SO você utiliza?

Comment: Adicionei sim, usando o windows 7, as configuracoes ficaram assim: 
zend_extension = "C:xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" e depois aquelas configuracoes padrões de porta e host, mas mesmo assim não consegui, se olho as configuracoes pelo phpinfo() mostra que o xdebug esta desabilitado

Comment: O certo é que utilizei uma versão antiga do xampp no qual ja vinha configurado o xdebug e funcionou. O ruim é usar uma versao antiga do xampp

Comment: No meu php.ini está indicada apenas a dll, assim `zend_extension = "php_xdebug.dll"`. O caminho dela é `c:\xampp\php\ext`. tkmattos não esqueça de colocar a arroba antes do nome do usuário para notifica-lo :)

Comment: ok @rray , obrigado pela valiosa ajuda, como o de costume

Answer (score 3):

O caminho padrão do `php.ini` do `xampp` é este:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Basta acessar e edita-lo.

Comment: A localização do php.ini é tranquilo, a duvida é como adicionar a extensao pelo php.ini, pois no xampp mais atual não encontrei as configurações, e mesmo adicionando a dll do xdebug não consegui fazer ele funcionar

Answer (score 2):

adicione a seguinte seção no seu php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "./php/ext/php_xdebug<version>.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<XAMPP_HOME>\tmp"
```

Fonte: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html

Comment: Since PHP 5.3, you always need to use the 'zend_extension', and NOT 'zend_extension_ts', 'zend_extension_debug' or 'extension'.