# Formulario PHP não grava

Tags: php, formulário, sql-insert

Tenho esse Form html:

```
<form id="addRunner" name="addRunner" action="service.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName" value="" placeholder="Firt Name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName" id="txtLastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
Gender: <select name="ddlGender" id="ddlGender">
         <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
         <option value="">Female</option>
         <option value="">Male</option>
</select><br>
Finish Time: <input type="text" name="txtMinutes" id="txtMinutes" value="" placeholder="(minutes)" maxlength="2">
<input type="text" name="txtSeconds" id="txtSeconds" size="10" maxlength="2" value="txtSeconds" placeholder="(seconds)">
<br><br>
<button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave">Add Runner</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action[]" id="action[]" value="addRunner">
</form>
```

Esse código PHP deveria fazer a validação e gravação na base da informações enviadas pelo Form, porém nada é gravado na Base. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$a_html = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if ($a_html === 'addRunner') {

    $fname = htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['txtFirstName']) ? $_POST['txtFirstName'] : 'txtFirstName');
    $lname = htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['txtLastName']) ? $_POST['txtLastName'] : 'txtLastName');
    $gender = htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['ddlGender']) ? $_POST['ddlGender'] : 'Valor Padrão');
    $minutes = htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['txtMinutes']) ? $_POST['txtMinutes'] : 'ddlGender');
    $seconds = htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['txtSeconds']) ? $_POST['txtSeconds'] : 'txtSeconds');
    $time = $minutes . ':' . $seconds;

    if (preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $fname) || preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $lname)) {
        echo 'Invalid name provided';
    }

    if (empty($gender)) {
        echo 'Gender select a please';
    }

    $string_sql = "INSERT INTO testemunho (first_name, last_name, gender, finish_time) VALUES (null,'{$fname}','{$lname}','{$gender}','{$time}')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conect, $string_sql);

    if ($result) {
        echo 'Runners: ', "$fname","$lname" . "Added Sucess";
    } else {
        echo 'Erro ao gravar dados';
    }
}
```

Comment: Use um script chamado JQueryMask que vai te ajudar mais do que filtrar campos no PHP. Provavelmente deve ter algum erro nestas filtragens via PH que estão te impedindo de gravar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Os colchetes tratam os elementos do mesmo nome como um array que não é o seu caso pois só tem um input hidden com `name="action[]"`. Mude esse name para `action` sem os colchetes para que [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) funcione corretamente e o script entre em `if ($a_html === 'addRunner') {`
2. Os values dos options estão vazios

   ```
    <option value="">Female</option>
    <option value="">Male</option>
   ```

   portanto sempre vai cair nesse `if`

   ```
   if (empty($gender)) {
      echo 'Gender select a please';
   }
   ```

   embora isso não cause erros, coloque valores nos values tipo `f` e `m` por exemplo.

> Feito isso seu INSERT deverá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que debugar melhor o seu código para entender em qual parte do código está gerando uma saída indesejada:

Considere utilizar a função do php `var_dump`.

Neste link tem algumas dicas: [Como debugar código em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6037/como-debugar-c%C3%B3digo-em-php)

E veja qual a saídas das variáveis: `$result`, `$string_sql`,`$a_html`